# file system allocated size for db field

Tags: java, mysql, database, filesystems

As an example you have database field call email and data type is varchar(100) so I'm going to save a email to that field of size 50 chars.

My question is what is the file system allocated size for it. If we consider 1 char is one byte is it 100 bytes or 50 bytes.

I need to know this because when I create table structure I want to more focus on data types and size.

Comment: Why did you use java tag?  It doesn't seem to be related to Java

Answer (score 0):

MySQL (and every reasonable RDBMS) will store only actual size of content in the varchar field with some small constant overhead. So the size would be close to 50 bytes. This is different to the char type, which will reserve the whole size, that's why using varchar is preferred in most situations.

See doc for MySQL here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html